# Google Maps API places library gives 404 error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

I use this library so that on certain input elements I can display an autocomplete list of places.

Until a few days ago, it was working fine. Now, it doesn't work and I noticed this error on my Chrome's console:

```
GET http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/10a/%7Bmain,places%7D.js?_=1343069114062 404 (Not Found)
```

I've come so far as to understanding that it's the **?_=1343069114062** part that is breaking (try http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/10a/%7Bmain,places%7D.js - works fine.)

Can you help me figure this out?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample page reproducing the problem?

Comment: @bamnet No, unfortunately I can't. I don't understand why the (first) script is trying to insert the other one, it should be without any ?... right? (check the last lines of [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false)

Comment: I looked at the URL of your first link and the script that gets loaded calls the second script in the last line, but without the ?_=1343069114062 part. It may have been a temporary glitch on Google's side. (It wouldn't be the first time that something goes wrong with a new release and then they roll it back.) BTW, +1 for a well written question.

Comment: @Marcelo Yes, I thought about that too, let's see if this eventually goes away. Thanks for the +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently something else on my document was interfering.

I just moved the script tag to another position in the document and everything now works fine.